# Nginx Modify Incoming Invalid Header

Tags: http, nginx, header

I've got a question about nginx configuration. I'm sending a request to nginx with a header which I know is invalid, and want to modify that header with nginx to make it valid.

request:

```
curl -X POST -d "data=string" -H "Host:192.168.99.100" -H "Connection: close" -H "Accept-Encoding: identity" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Content-Length: 22\r\n" -i http://192.168.99.100/protocol_1.2
```

Note the Content-Length: 22\r\n (CRLF)

Then in error.log, with loglevel INFO I get

```
[info] 5#0: *1 client sent invalid "Content-Length" hader while reading client request headers, client: 192.168.99.1, server: example.org,request: "POST /protocol_1.2 HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.99.100"
```

Unfortunately I cannot modify the source of the request, so want to modify it in nginx instead. Is there a way for me to modify incoming headers before they are processes by nginx?

My sites-enabled is pretty simple:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name example.org;
    charset utf-8;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log info;

    ignore_invalid_headers on;

    location /static {
        alias /usr/src/app/static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://music:8010;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}
```

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

This argument:

```
-H "Content-Length: 22\r\n"
```

Should probably be:

```
-H "Content-Length: 22"
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try 'ignore_invalid_headers' in the nginx.conf.
FYI